# Display the selected option on a select with a different text Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have done this select

```
<select [(ngModel)]="phoneCode" name="paises">
   <option *ngFor="let pais of (paises$ | async)" [value]="pais.phonecode">{{pais.nicename}} (+{{pais.phonecode}})</option>
</select>
```

I need to show the **selected** option with only the code (without the country name). How can I do it? I have it like the first picture, I need it like the last one.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove only the part where you use string interpoloation.

{{pais.nicename}} needs to be removed

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="phoneCode" name="paises">
   <option *ngFor="let pais of (paises$ | async)" [value]="pais.phonecode">(+{{pais.phonecode}})</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I always need the pais.nicename and the pais.phonecode in the drop-down list, like the second picture. What I want is delete the pais.nicename where you see a +61 (second picture).